# Android MVVM architecture ViewModel not calling one by one

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I am working with MVVM pattern for api call and working good.

My issue is in my activity i created three different *ViewModels* for calling different APIs based on some API response.

Now when one API execute then some value from its response needs to pass to other API view model so using that i can get response. But some how in my activity all there view models called at same time so i m not getting proper response.

So what is the best way to register observe using *MVVM* one by one so it work proper.

```java
void getInspirationDetails() {

        inspirationDetailsModel.getInspirationDetails(userid, deviceId, inspirationId, Constants.PLATFORM).observe(InspirationUploadDetailsActivity.this, new Observer<MainInspirationDetailsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(MainInspirationDetailsResponse mainInspirationDetailsResponse) {
            }
     }

    void getProducts() {

        productsDetailsModel.getProductsItems(inspirationId, "", "N", "ALL", "", "").observe(this, new Observer<MainProductsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(MainProductsResponse mainProductsResponse) {


                }
            }
        });
```

Both functions called at same time which i don't need.

Thanks in Advance!``

Comment: where you have call these methods?

Comment: It's in _onCreate()_

Comment: call the second methode after receive the response from methode one. dnt call both `onCreate`

Comment: Though it's call first i did that

Comment: i dont get what you said?

Comment: I put in response of first API though both called at same time

Comment: can you post your `onCreate` methode here?

Comment: Post your code where you actually calling the API in ViewModel or via the repository.